# numpy correlation coefficient error - RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

Tags: python, numpy

I get the following error when I try to find the correlation between to data series:

```
>>> i = [1, 1, 1]
>>> j = [2, 2, 2]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.corrcoef(i, j)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3003: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
 c /= stddev[:, None]
 array([[ nan,  nan],  
       [ nan,  nan]])`
```

Experimenting a bit, I find that this seems to occur only when all integers in an array are the same. Is this expected or am I doing something wrong? Most of the cases I expect the data in i and j to have differing values, but there may be cases when they are the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encountered invalid value when I use pearsonr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653993/encountered-invalid-value-when-i-use-pearsonr)

Comment: They are not series, they are points essentially. You can't find correlation coefficiant for a point. what do you expect the answer to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python numpy.corrcoef() RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true\_divide c /= stddev\[:, None\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897003/python-numpy-corrcoef-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-true-divide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the standard deviation of series and proceed for correlation if they are more than zero with an if statement.

Comment: You don't need an if statement.. If you look at the array, there is simply no variation, hence standard deviation is zero

Comment: Apparently, but I consider the question in a broad sense, not only the sample data series provided here.

Answer (score 1):

in the formula for correlation, the calculation divides by the standard deviation of each series. In your case, the stds are zero.