# Python numpy.corrcoef() RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide c /= stddev[:, None]

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

It seems that `corrcoef` from `numpy` throw a **RuntimeWarning** when a constant list passed to the `corrcoef()` function, for example the below code throw a warning :

```
import numpy as np
X = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
Y = [2, 2, 2, 2]
print(np.corrcoef(X, Y)[0, 1])
```

Warning :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:3003: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  c /= stddev[:, None]
```

Can anyone explain why it's throwing this error when one of the lists is constant and how to prevent this error when a constant list is passed to the function?

Comment: The error is probably occurring because the standard deviation (`stddev`) of the constant list `Y` is `0`. I'm not sure that it makes sense to calculate the covariance of something with respect to something that's constant...

Comment: @JoshKarpel So covariance of a constant variable is undifined?

Comment: A [quick Google](http://www.kaspercpa.com/statisticalreview.htm) (Covariance Rule #4) indicates that the covariance of a random variable with respect to a constant is zero. So it's not undefined, but any algorithm for calculating the covariance numerically probably assumes that it won't be zero.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Correlation is a measure of how well two vectors track with each other as they change.  You can't track mutual change when one vector doesn't change.

As noted in OP comments, the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Definition) for Pearson's product-moment correlation coefficient divides the covariance of `X` and `Y` by the product of their standard deviations.  Since `Y` has zero variance in your example, its standard deviation is also zero.  That's why you get the `true_divide` error - you're trying to divide by zero.

Note: It might seem tempting, from an engineering standpoint, to simply add a very small quantity (say, a value just above machine epsilon) onto one of the entries in `Y`, in order to get around the zero-division issue.  But that's not statistically viable.  Even adding `1e-15` will seriously derange your correlation coefficient, depending on which value you add it to.

Consider the difference between these two cases:

```
X = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

tiny = 1e-15

# add tiny amount to second element
Y1 = [2., 2.+tiny, 2., 2.]
np.corrcoef(X, Y1)[0, 1] 
-0.22360679775

# add tiny amount to fourth element
Y2 = [2., 2., 2., 2.+tiny]
np.corrcoef(X, Y2)[0, 1]
0.67082039325
```

This may be obvious to statisticians, but given the nature of the question it seems like a relevant caveat.

Comment: How to ignore the warning?

Answer (score 1):

The Pandas .corr is more versatile in such conditions and even presence of NaN(s), so first option could be to convert the lists to pandas series and use the pandas correlation and the response would be a nan;

```
import pandas as pd
X = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
Y = [2, 2, 2, 2]
print(pd.Series(X).corr( pd.Series(Y)))
```

If you want to stick to numpy then you can check the standard deviation of series using an if statement, and proceed for correlation only when they are more than zero. Apparently here we have no valid output because one list has no variation, but the concept could be applied to other cases.

```
import numpy as np
X = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
Y = [2, 2, 2, 2]
if np.std(Y)==0 or np.std(X)==0 :
    print ('The correlation could not be computed because the standard deviation of one of the series is equal to zero')
else:
    print(np.corrcoef(X, Y)[0, 1])
```

Comment: So what is the solution when the question is repeated? Similar answers are required or to be able to merge the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "fixed" version of `np.corrcoef`:

```
def pearsonccs(samples):
    C = np.cov(samples)
    diag = np.diag(C)
    N = np.sqrt(np.outer(diag, diag))
    N[N == 0] = 1
    return C / N
```

All it does is replacing the zeroes in the covariance matrix with one to avoid the divide-by-zero-error.

Answer (score 1):

If you would just like to suppress the warning, you can modify the function like this:

```
import numpy as np
X = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
Y = [2, 2, 2, 2]
with np.errstate(divide="ignore", invalid="ignore"): 
    print(np.corrcoef(X, Y))
```

That should make it robust to divisions by zero and `NaN` values.