# Python numpy.corrcoef() got different result in different float number when two doesn't change vector

Tags: numpy, statistics, data-analysis, numerical-methods

```py
import numpy as np

len = 999

a = np.array([1.0]*len)
b = np.array([3.5]*len)

print(np.corrcoef(a, b))

a = np.array([0.9]*len)
b = np.array([3.4]*len)

print(np.corrcoef(a, b))
```

Got result:

```
[[nan nan]
 [nan nan]]

[[ 1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.]]
```

I think both results should be below:

```
[[ 1. 1.]
  [1. 1.]]
```

or

```
[[nan nan]
 [nan nan]]
```

Why got different result between different constant float number?

Comment: This appears to be due to floating point error; when you compute `np.std(np.array([1.0]*len))` you get zero exactly, but when you compute `np.std(np.array([0.9]*len))` you get some number close to zero.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897003/python-numpy-corrcoef-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-true-divide

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer should be na for all, because definition for correlation is (from wiki):

[image]

If all your observations are the same, the denominator is 0, so you are dividing by zero.

In instances where the denominator is not exactly zero, you get a -1, 1 value, which is not correct.

You can use a higher precision and you get:

```
np.corrcoef(np.array([0.9]*len),np.array([3.4]*len),dtype = np.float128)
```

My suggestion is that check your entries before correlating. No point making the correlation between two vectors with no variation.