# np.corrcoef returns only nan

Tags: python, numpy, pearson-correlation

i have an array

```
norm_array=np.array([[1, 133, 1, 5.73, 5.09, 11.12, 10.16, 3.38, 15, 3, 8, 7, 4, 5, 1,
    6, 1, 2, 18, 12, 48],
   [1, 185, 0, 4.34, 3.66, 18.23, 14.91, 0, 21, 15, 11, 2, 4, 4, 5,
    4, 9, 8, 27, 14, 47],
   [1, 133, 1, 5.92, 4.63, 9.66, 7.77, 7.18, 9, 20, 4, 11, 9, 1, 7,
    5, 3, 7, 29, 1, 45],
   [1, 165, 1, 4.26, 4.57, 16.05, 16.21, 8.81, 17, 17, 5, 10, 7, 7,
    6, 3, 8, 6, 29, 7, 40],
   [1, 48, 11, 7.13, 8.51, 15.43, 17.74, 11.49, 20, 14, 6, 12, 6, 7,
    6, 8, 8, 6, 39, 16, 38]])
```

i want to calculate a correlation, but np.corrcoef returns nan

```
cor=[]
f=norm_array[:, 0]
for j in range(norm_array.shape[1]):
      s=norm_array[:, j]
      cor.append(np.corrcoef(f.astype(np.float32), s.astype(np.float32))[0, 1])
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lKl1.png)

Comment: I think this answer is what you're looking for: [numpy.corrcoef()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897003/python-numpy-corrcoef-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-true-divide)

Comment: Do you mean to do np.corrcoef(np.transpose(norm_array))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are computing the [Pearson correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) between two vectors `f` and `s`. This needs the value for the standard deviation of both vectors. Since `f` consists of only ones, the standard deviation is 0 and because you need to divide by this value, it gives you nan's.

When printing `f`:

```
>>> f
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
```

Changing the first value of `norm_array` to for example `2` will give 'normal' results.

Comment: thank you, I noticed that the first column was just a test one and didn't need to be used :)