# Apply a function to two equally shaped numpy matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, correlation

I am looking for the most elegant way to apply a statistical function between two matrices (some kind of mapping / one two one operation). Here is my function applied to two 20 items long distributions

```
stats.pearsonr(data["histograms"][0][15][2], regions_hist[0][15][2])[0]
> 0.42524395175128987
```

Both matrices have the same shape

```
data["histograms"][0].shape
> (16, 3, 20)
regions_hist[0].shape
> (16, 3, 20)
```

What I am looking for would be a way to

```
Correlations = FancyMapping(data["histograms"][0],regions_hist[0])
Correlations.shape  # matrix with the 16*3 correlations between items of both
>(16,3)
```

Do you think of any elegant solution (the shaping aspect matters for my problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your example is already in the docs, see the bottom of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html. So

```
import scipy.stats
pearsonr = np.vectorize(scipy.stats.pearsonr, signature='(n),(n)->(),()')
correlations = pearsonr(data["histograms"][0],regions_hist[0])
```

should work :)

Comment: It won't work in common case. You should specify the number of brackets in signature that corresponds to the output shape of the statistical function. In mentioned case signature has to be `(n),(n)->()`.

Comment: Actually the signature is correct because scipy.stats.pearsonr returns a tuple with 2 values, (r, p), see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html

Comment: My bad, didn't pay attention to function's name... But saw clearly that one returned value `> 0.42524395175128987` was mentioned.

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py:3021: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  r = r_num / r_den

Comment: my first column is full of "nans"

Comment: Are you sure that this data is 'good'? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653993/encountered-invalid-value-when-i-use-pearsonr answer your problem?

Comment: My bad, it is completely normal that I get some nans here and there, given my data. I could even use this information later on