# matrix correlation gives (nan) values?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, nan

looking for a way to find the correlation of the "y" matrix but I always get (nan) values as a result!!!! here's my code.

```
n_r = len(y)
n_c = len(y)
A = sparse.dok_matrix((n_r, n_c), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(n_r):
    for j in range(n_c):
        v_i = X.toarray()[i, :]
        v_j = X.toarray()[j, :]
        print(v_j)
        correlation = stats.pearsonr(v_i, v_j)
        print(correlation)
```

Comment: What is the variable `X`?

Comment: Please provide a working example of the code. Even if it yields an error, at least include everything you are using, e.g. `y` in this case, and the `import`s you are using etc.

Comment: X is my vocab matrix

Comment: import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
from scipy import sparse, stats
am using these imports

Comment: Could you by any chance have either ```v_i``` or ```v_j``` composed of only one value? Something like ```v_i = [0, 0, 0, ..., 0]``` with only zeroes? In that case ```scipy.stats.pearsonr``` would output you a ```nan``` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653993/encountered-invalid-value-when-i-use-pearsonr).